# Icon names are getting flikr after click on menu bar

Tags: html, css, react-bootstrap, sidebar

On react js page I have a sidebar which contains icons and icon names, previous am using a CDB library but I have removed that library
But while open menu bar icon names are getting flikr
Is there any way to not get flikr icon names after opening the menu bar

Below is my code

```
    <CDBSidebar id="left-sidebar" >
        <CDBSidebarHeader className="sidebar-top" prefix={<i className='fa fa-bars'/>}}>Dashboard</CDBSidebarHeader>
          <CDBSidebarContent>
            <div className='sidebar-menu'>
              <ul className='sidebar-ul'>
              <li className='sidebar-li'>
                  <FaSearch className='react-icons' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Search" />
                    <span>Search</span>
                </li>                
                <li className='sidebar-li'>
                  <FaGlobe data-toggle="tooltip" title="Option" />
                    <span>Options</span> 
                </li>                
              </ul>
            </div>
        </CDBSidebarContent>
    </CDBSidebar>
```

I have added the image while showing the flikr names after clicking on Dashboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Shii.png)